# Keep room for system-node-critical pods on k8s nodes

Tags: kubernetes

We have a k8s cluster with autoscaling and run our jobs with [Guaranteed QoS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/#create-a-pod-that-gets-assigned-a-qos-class-of-guaranteed) to avoid them being moved around (as these cannot be restarted side-effect free). This works fine, however we sometimes have some small pods that need to run on every k8s node. We mark these with `system-node-critical` so that they will be scheduled on every node (this works as well).

However, this naturally might evict some of our normal pods. I wonder if it's possible to allow normal jobs to only occupy 80% of resources per node, so we always have some room for the critical pods (as long as they stay <20% of resources).

We're on k8s 1.22 if that helps.

Comment: I think that topologySpreadConstraints could help you.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/#topologyspreadconstraints-field

Comment: priorityClasses such as system-node-critical would always have the same weight/score, there is no way to say "keep 80% of my lesser-critical workloads intact". If a workload has priority over another, and when that other workload can be preempted, then it will be evicted